# How to call non-static function in remotelisten of ignite-messaging lambda function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, messaging, ignite

I have a class (TopicListenerImp) that listens topic and I want to get the message comes from remoteListen function and give as parameter to another non-static functions in other service classes.

```
     @Component
    public class TopicListenerImp implements TopicListener {


      private NotificationService notificationService;
      private SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;
      private SubscriptionRules subscriptionRules;
      private NFInstancesService nfInstancesService;
      private Ignite ignite;

      public TopicListenerImp(
          SubscriptionRules subscriptionRules,
          NotificationService notificationService,
          SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository,
          Ignite ignite,
          NFInstancesService nfInstancesService) {
        this.subscriptionRules = subscriptionRules;
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.subscriptionRepository = subscriptionRepository;
        this.nfInstancesService = nfInstancesService;
        this.ignite = ignite;
      }

      @Bean
      public void startTopicListening() {

        IgniteMessaging rmtMsg = ignite.message(ignite.cluster().forLocal());
        rmtMsg.remoteListen(
            "SUSPEND",
            (nodeId, msg) -> {

              notifyIfSubscriptionExist((String) msg); //here where I used the message that comes from topic
              return true; 
            });
      }

      public void notifyIfSubscriptionExist(String msg) {

        List<String> nfInstanceIdSubscriptionId = parseNfInstanceIdSubscriptionId(msg);
        Optional<NFProfile> nfProfile =
            nfInstancesService.getNFInstance(nfInstanceIdSubscriptionId.get(0));
        Optional<SubscriptionData> subscriptionDataOptional =
            subscriptionRepository.getSubscriptionData(nfInstanceIdSubscriptionId.get(1));

        subscriptionDataOptional.ifPresent(
            subscriptionData -> {
              if (subscriptionRules.checkRules(subscriptionData) && nfProfile.isPresent())
                notificationService.sendEventNotification(
                    subscriptionData, nfProfile.get(), NF_PROFILE_CHANGED);
            });
      }

      private List<String> parseNfInstanceIdSubscriptionId(String msg) {
        List<String> values = asList(msg.split(", "));
        return asList(getIdFromMessage(values.get(0)), getIdFromMessage(values.get(1)));
      }

      private String getIdFromMessage(String msg) {
        return msg.substring(msg.indexOf('[') + 1, msg.length() - 1);
      }
    }
```

But I get following errors;

```
    Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object etc.
```

When I inject fields statically, it works. But when I do this, the IDE gives warnings "don't update the static variable from the constructor method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[remoteListen](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteMessaging.html#remoteListen-java.lang.Object-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate-) takes a predicate, that will be serialized and sent to remote nodes over network. When you call a non-static method within its implementation, it makes the whole `this` object be serialized. It may lead to unexpected behaviour and tons of data sent over network.

In general it's not recommended to send lambda functions over network, since their serialization is VM-dependent and it doesn't give you control of what you actually send. If you want to send a predicate over network, then create a class implementing the predicate interface and use an instance of this class.

If you don't need all nodes in the cluster to subscribe to the topic, then [localListen](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteMessaging.html#localListen-java.lang.Object-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate-) will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the comment localListen works like charm, but I have a question. localListen takes predicate either, how come it doesnt want staticness?

Comment: The issue that you had with a remote listener came from the requirement to serialize it. But the local one is not sent anywhere, so there is no need to serialize anything.